# Jquery text returning weird values

Tags: jquery, return, alert

My code is gerating strange output, I just want to get value of an element, but it returns me some kind of code. Sorry if it was a fool question, I am starting in JavaScript:

```
function clicarBotao(id){
    var text=$("#"+id).html;    
    alert(text);
}
</script>

<body>
...
<ul>
<li id="1" class="botaoMenu" onclick="clicarBotao(1)">Menu 1</li>
</ul>
...
</body>
```

Alert returns:

```
function ( value ) {
        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
            var elem = this[0] || {},
                i = 0,
                l = this.length;

            if ( value === undefined ) {
                return elem.nodeType === 1 ?
                    elem.innerHTML.replace( rinlinejQuery, "" ) :
                    undefined;
            }
```

code does not end here ...

Comment: avoid using numbers as an id....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `html()`, not `html`. It is printing the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
function clicarBotao(id){
   //var text=$("#"+id).html; you use html
    var text=$("#"+id).html();   //here use html() not html 
    alert(text);
}
```

reference **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**